# Access the results of a query

Tags: php, mysql

AM using a database class to query data from a database, i want to access specific values from the results

```php
class Database 
{
    private $host = myServer;
    private $db   = database; 
    private $username = uid;
    private $pwd = password;

    private $connection;
    private $stmt;
    private $error;
    private $dbconnected=false; 
    
    public function __construct()
    {
        $dsn = 'mysql:host='.$this->host.';dbname='.$this->db;
        $options=array(PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT =>true,
                       PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE=> PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

        try{

            $this->connection= new PDO($dsn,$this->username, $this->pwd, $options);

            $this->dbconnected=true;

        }
        catch(PDOException $e){

            $this->error = $e->getMessage().PHP_EOL;
        }

    }

    public function geterror(){
         return $this->error;
    }

    public function isConnected(){
        return $this->dbconnected;
    }

    public function query($query){
        $this->stmt=$this->connection->prepare($query);
    }

    public function execute(){
        return $this->stmt->execute();
    }

    public function resultset(){
    $this->execute();
        return $this->stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    }

    Public function rowCount(){
        return $this->stmt->rowCount();
    }

    public function single(){
        $this->execute();
        return $this->stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    }

    public function bind($param,$value,$type=null){
          if(is_null($type))
          {
            switch (true) {
                case is_int($value):
                    $type=PDO::PARAM_INT;
                    break;
                case is_bool($value):
                    $type=PDO::PARAM_BOOL;
                case is_null($value):
                    $type=PDO::PARAM_NULL;
                default:
                    $type=PDO::PARAM_STR;
                    break;
            }
          }

          $this->stmt->bindValue($param,$value,$type);
    }

}
```

this is my code to fetch data from the database, the database has two field(id,Name). I want to get value of the name field

```php
$db = new database();
$db->query("SELECT * FROM ministry WHERE id=:id");
$db->bind(':id',$tid);
$result = $db->single();

var_dump($result);
```

Comment: Well your query should return an object (per the code of your single() function), so just use object syntax?? Try `echo $result->name;`. If you'd showed us the output of `var_dump($result);` we could have given you the solution with more confidence.

Comment: Case is significant. So it should be `$result->Name`.